# Creation of database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am unable to create a database in SQL Server 2008. This is the message that I recieve every time:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Create failed for Database 'university'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=262&LinkId=20476
```

What should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the permission of the logged in user.
Solution 1)
Click on Start -> Click in Microsoft SQL Server 2005
Now right click on SQL Server Management Studio
Click on Run as administrator

Solution2)

check with `select user_name()` if you are not logged in as guest.

Add a domain account as sysadmin to SQL Express with SQLCMD

```
Start a command shell elevated
type SQLCMD –S (local)\sqlexpress

CREATE LOGIN [your domain account] FROM WINDOWS;
```

check if the login is created successfully

```
SELECT NAME FROM SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS
```

Grant sysadmin rights

```
SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER ‘darth\vader’, ‘sysadmin’
```

Reference : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the account your using permission to create databases.

You may need to login using the `sa` account and perform a `GRANT` on the user account.

```
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO YourAccount;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx